# #!/bin/csh Cshell check find result if else

Tags: linux, shell, csh

**Goal**: Checking find result, if empty echo something, if not echo find result

```
#!/bin/csh
set mtime = 0;
echo "<i>Title</i>" >> $outputfile
set text=`find start*middle*.txt -mtime $mtime -ls`
echo "$text" >> $outputfile
```

I have tried the following (all failed) ...

```
if (-f "$text" ) then
    echo Exists
else
    echo No such file
endif
```

-

```
if [[ -n $(find start*middle*.txt -mtime $mtime -ls) ]]
then
 echo "res" >> $outputfile
fi
```

-

```
if [[ -n "$text" ]]
then
 echo "res" >> $outputfile
fi
```

Comment: I don't think `*csh` has `[[ ]]`

Comment: Perhabs ...Just trying out things I found on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `csh`? It's really [not recommended for scripting](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).

Comment: Huge company, remote / old servers, won't be updated in the foreseeable future. Maybe I can use Node to call a javascript-script, probably easier to read the directory once and loop through the filesnames and do my magic with jquery...

Comment: Surely said old servers have plain `sh` as well?

Comment: BTW, https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt is another essay written as a follow-up to the link chepner gave above.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/csh
set outputfile = test
set mtime = 0;
echo "<i>Title</i>" >> $outputfile
set text=`find start*middle*.txt -ls`
if ("$text" != "") then
        echo "exists"
else
        echo "dosn't exist"
endif
echo "$text" >> $outputfile
```

If you need to use the `-mtime` option a value of 0 is incorrect.
If you want to list files created in the last day you need `-mtime -1` and 
for 2 days `-mtime -2`

Comment: @DavidDunham did you try this solution?